# How can I use ctags with vim?

Tags: vim, ctags

I have created a *tags* file using ctags in my source code directory. Now, how can I use it with vim? If I open a file and press ctrl-] on a variable or function name, vim says: *E426: tag not found: variable1*

Comment: Correct answer: "read the `tags` docs". It's all covered in the docs, as usual. Vim documentation is *good*.

Comment: I would recommend you to use plugin Indexer: http://goo.gl/gkFPp  It provides painless automatic tags generation for whole project(s) and keeps tags up-to-date. You can read some details in my answer to another question: http://goo.gl/Rpyha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:set tags=/home/ptomblin/ctags,/usr/local/src/ctags
```

You can put that in your main .vimrc file.